# "Layer loading" progress bar

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, progress

Is there a way of showing the progress when adding a layer though QgsVectorLayer(url, name, "ogr") in pyqgis? Some of the layers I am adding are quite large, and take some time to load.

Excample:

```
    url = "http://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighettettsted?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258&typeNames=app:TettstedHCparkering&"

    new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(url, "LayerName", "ogr") #this part might take long time

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
```

Comment: Do you want the message bar when you add a layer in the layer panel or when display it in map canvas? The first it's instantaneous; the second depends on layer dimension (as you pointed), and it's repeated every time you pan the map. So showing up a message bar every time I pan I think it's a bit annoying.... This is only my opinion :)

Comment: sorry for asking but ... what do u call _"adding a layer through QgsVectorLayer"_ ? Which method do u intend to use ?

Comment: @OscarCampo I want the progress bar to show when I am useing QgsVectorLayer(url, name, "ogr"), and possible some other functions following that one. The url is for a WFS client. It can take up to a minute, depending on the specifications of the url.

Comment: @snaileater I am talking about  QgsVectorLayer(url, name, "ogr"), where the url is for a WFS Client.

Comment: Through `QgsVectorLayer()` constructor you only create an instance of  `QgsVectorLayer`  class. Sorry but it's unclear what are you askink for. Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: @OscarCampo Sure, added it in now. From testing, it is the second line that might be a bit slow depending on the url

Comment: I think maybe you have to use multithreading. Try this [https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2013/12/07/multithreading-in-qgis-python-plugins/](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2013/12/07/multithreading-in-qgis-python-plugins/)